# Dynamically programming a grid consisting of 64 buttons (8x8)

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, button, grid

I'm trying to create a chess game purely for my learning C# and chess. Just to start off with, I would like to create an 8x8 grid of buttons through code rather than the designer. This would save me hard coding each button individually.

A button array would seem a good way to start but I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: just to add im using visual studio 2010 and am creating this suign winforms

Comment: Update your question instead of adding this kind of comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        int ButtonWidth = 40;
        int ButtonHeight = 40;
        int Distance = 20;
        int start_x = 10;
        int start_y = 10;

        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                Button tmpButton = new Button();
                tmpButton.Top = start_x + (x * ButtonHeight + Distance);
                tmpButton.Left = start_y + (y * ButtonWidth + Distance);
                tmpButton.Width = ButtonWidth;
                tmpButton.Height = ButtonHeight;
                tmpButton.Text = "X: " + x.ToString() + " Y: " + y.ToString();
                // Possible add Buttonclick event etc..
                this.Controls.Add(tmpButton);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a "square" class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


class Square:PictureBox
{
   private bool color;
   private char piece;
}
```

and define an array to make place for 8x8 squares.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 Square[,] square = new Square[8, 8];

 public Form1()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
     for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     {
       this.square[i, j] = new Square();//Creating the chess object//
       this.square[i, j].BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
       this.square[i, j].BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
       this.square[i, j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(57 + i * 40, 109 + j * 40);
       this.square[i, j].Name = "chessBox1";
       this.square[i, j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
       this.square[i, j].TabIndex = 2;
       this.square[i, j].TabStop = false;
       this.Controls.Add(this.square[i, j]);
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: although the answer by StephanE is more suited to what id like to implement now, your code is any opener to alternate ways of doing things, ill certainly look into this more, i really appreciate your help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

May be you ca use the code below to solve your problem. This code is of Windows Form application in C#. And for the control Button.

```
    for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++)    
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      {
        Button BtnNew = new Button;
        BtnNew.Height = 80;
        BtnNew.Width = 80;
        BtnNew.Location = new Point(80*i, 80*j);
        this.Controls.Add(BtnNew);
       }
}
```

Comment: thank you. very similar to the code above, ill certainly try this in my model.